# Название методов для работы с MySql PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Пишу свой класс для работы с MySql через PDO.
Хочу упростить писанину, вопрос только как назвать метод, что бы потом не было проблем в следующих версиях PHP. Вдруг они придумают функцию схожим с названием мои методов.

Хочу просто упросюить занесение данных в бд. Пишу такой метод, который будет в `(ключ массива, ключ массива) VALUES (значение массива, значение массива)`.

Если я назову метод `select`, то будет понятно, но глупо, а если назову `DB_select` или `PDO_select` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так в php вроде есть [пространства имён](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php).

Если запихнёте свои классы в пространство вроде `my_super_pdo`:

```
<?php namespace my_super_pdo;
  class PDO{
    static function DB_select() {
      echo 'meoow';
    }  
  } 
?>
```

вряд ли возникнут проблемы

Comment: Если namespace `my_super_pdo;` то метод будет называться `namespace my_super_pdo` а не `DB_select`? То есть мне нужно определить в начале `namespace DB_select;` ?

Comment: @Владимир вызывать метод так `my_super_pdo\PDO::DB_select()` или если определить `namespace my_super_pdo;` сверху, то `PDO::DB_select()`

Answer (score 2):

Почему глупо-то?

Неймспейсы здесь не при чем. Они относятся к именам **классов**. А внутри самого класса никаких неймспейсов не нужно. РНР не будет придумывать новых функций для твоего класса.

Какой смысл повторяться и писать `$pdo->pdo_select()` или `DB::db_select()`? Вот это как раз и будет глупо.

А еще глупее называть словом select метод, который выполняет запрос INSERT

Comment: А как тогда его лучше назвать?

Comment: Назвать его словом insert?

Comment: @Ипатьев: Не хватает вашего ответа: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476368/10105

Comment: @VladD ответ, полезный автору, будет оффтопиком для сайта. Люди будут приходить из гугла за ответом на то, как запретить, а им будут писать про подготовленные выражения. Ему надо либо переформулировать вопрос, либо задать его заново.

Comment: @Ипатьев: Я имел в виду скорее «полезный для сайта», чем «для автора». Хотя да, канонический ответ про bobby tables должен быть не на этот вопрос.

Comment: @VladD об этом я и говорю, да.