# Как в MySQL запретить все команды, кроме заранее перечисленных?

Tags: mysql

Как в MySQL запретить все команды, кроме заранее перечисленных? Если команды нету в списке, то MySQL её обрабатывать не будет.

Comment: вы, возможно, спрашивали про [это](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)? Т.е. при создании пользователя задаете ему какие [привилегии](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-privileges) ему доступны (либо указываете это уже после его создания)

Comment: Для этих целей, мне кажется, придумано ограничение прав пользователей на таблицы.

Comment: Интересно. Но я спрашиваю с той целью,  что бы   было невозможно, провести SQL инъекцию.

Comment: @semiromid: Чтобы невозможно было провести SQL-инъекцию, нужно просто не склеивать строки от пользователя в команды SQL. Никогда. Читали: http://bobby-tables.com/ ?

Comment: VladD - можете  показать пример как делать не надо, что бы я точно был уверен что понял Вас правильно? Читал похожее но не это. Почитаю , спасибо.

Comment: @semiromid, вы не понимаете ее суть. Если вы разрешите select (а он нужен, чтоыб данные выбирать) - инъекция уже возможна. Да, пользователь не сможет так грохнуть всю базу, либо изменить данные, но, например, залогиниться под чужим ником, либо получить нужные ему данные - он сможет. Если разрешите только обновление - инъекция уже возможна. Т.е. чтобы исключить инъекцию - надо выключить комп, спрятать его в каком-нибудь сейфе и забыть код доступа к нему, либо фильтровать пользовательськие данные и корректно их вставлять в sql

Comment: BOPOH - Вы правы, я суть очень слабо понимаю SQL инъекции. Только сегодня прочитал об этом, что её проводят методом склейки, или модификации, подставления своих данных в запрос.

Comment: BOPOH - а может быть если в SQL сделать свои процедуры и проверять на входные и выходные данные, было бы хорошо, как Вы считаете?

Comment: @semiromid: Ну почитайте же сайт! Там примеры на всех возможных языках. Или начните хотя бы отсюда: http://explainxkcd.com/327/

Comment: VladD там русский язык для галочки

Comment: @semiromid, посмотрите примеры [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php): через bindParam вы корректно вставляете значение в ваш запрос, так что никакие инъекции не страшны. Дополнительно почитайте [owasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) и статью там же [по предотвращению инъекции](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: BOPOH - а не корректно вставлять значения в SQL запрос, это как?

Comment: @semiromid, на русском можно почитать хотя бы документацию по php, например, [это](http://php.net/manual/ru/security.database.sql-injection.php), там и описано что это, и приведены ссылки на возможные инструменты (например, [это](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php) или [это](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)). *не корректно вставлять значения* - это так: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = $login AND password = $password"` - т.е. как вы и сказали - простой склейкой без какой-либо обработки

Comment: Я читал как раз там на русском.Я первый день с инъекциями связан, просто.

Comment: BOPOH - Вы мне показали обычный SQL запрос, чем он не обычный? $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = $login AND password = $password"  . То что он в переменную $sql вставлен?

Comment: @semiromid, а тем, что его легко сломать, передав в $login значение `1' OR login = 'admin'; --` - и у меня в итоге sql будет вида `SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '1' OR login = 'admin'; -- AND password = '...'`. Т.е. логиниться я буду либо как юзер с login = 1 (которого нет), либо (что вероятнее) как админ (`--` - все что после него это комментарий). Т.е. на лицо инъекция. Если же через биндинг это делать, то все входные параметры будут экранированы, а значит будет поиск логина вида `1' OR login = 'admin'; --`

Comment: BOPOH - ППЦ, я ранее именно так и писал  API. Тогда вообще ничего не понимаю как правильно.

Comment: BOPOH - использовать подготовленные выражения - выход? Ведь как без переменных данные в БД заносить когда данные все разные.

Comment: @semiromid, вы ссылки читали? там про это прямо [написано](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php): *Параметры подготовленного запроса не требуется экранировать кавычками; драйвер это делает автоматически. Если в приложении используются исключительно подготовленные запросы, разработчик может быть уверен, что никаких SQL инъекций случиться не может (однако, если другие части текста запроса записаны с неэкранированными символами, SQL инъекции все же возможны; здесь речь идет именно о параметрах)*

Comment: BOPOH - Я читал, и еще буде читать пока все не попробую и не пойму  досконально.  Но я подготовленные запросы еще не делал. Вот мой код: $result = mysqli_query($mys, "SELECT userid FROM users WHERE login='".$Login."' AND password='".$Password."'");   Но он расположен в функции, и глобальных переменных не имеет. Я так понимаю что он не правильный . Верно?  Кстати, с наступающим Новым Годом Вас!)

Comment: @semiromid: Вы в принципе никогда не должны сами клеить SQL из строк. Разве что вы **очень** хорошо понимаете, что делаете. Если не совсем, то лучше не надо.

Comment: VladD - я не могу к сожалению понять что значит клеить (как можно без конкатенации), а как можно по другому это делать, если там именно переменные нужны,  потому что данные все разные в БД нужно загружать. Разве что можно процедуры в самой MySQL написать, тогда клеить не придется, а использовать в PHP только процедуры для БД, которые написаны в самой MySQL. Так не, все равно переменные нужно будет использовать, но правда без конкатенации.

Comment: @semiromid: Клеить — это конкатенация. Вот именно конкатенация и есть причина SQL-инъекций. А как правильно делать, мы вам пытаемся втолковать в комментариях.

Comment: VladD - а как правильно такой запрос написать ?  - $result = mysqli_query($mys, "SELECT userid FROM users WHERE login='".$Login."' AND password='".$Password."'");

Comment: Параметры подготовленного запроса не требуется экранировать кавычками; драйвер это делает автоматически. Если в приложении используются исключительно подготовленные запросы, разработчик может быть уверен, что никаких SQL инъекций случиться не может (однако, если другие части текста запроса записаны с неэкранированными символами, SQL инъекции все же возможны; здесь речь идет именно о параметрах).

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю, "Подготовленный запрос" - это и есть процедура в MySQL, написанная с самим запросом. А в PHP,например, только вызываем как бы шаблон, этой процедуры?

Comment: @semiromid: [Вот тут](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) есть примеры кода. Один из них: `$stmt = $db->prepare('select userid from users where login = ? and password = ?');` Но я не спец, спросите лучше у спецов.

Comment: $stmt = $db->prepare('update people set name = ? where id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('si',$name,$id);
$stmt->execute();   - Это интересно. Ну что же, хех( Что бы быть хорошем веб-программистом, нужно быть хорошем хакером. Придется им стать . Я так не могу больше писать код, кода его можно взломать.

Comment: Я понял как 'это' делать. Хех( Плохо что это все есть. Неужели никого в этом мире не найдется что бы разработали нормальную систему без подобных дыр.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В MySQL есть оператор `GRANT`. Нужно создать нового пользователя (не использовать `root`) и дать ему права на исполнения некоторых операторов.

Пример синтаксиса:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

в этом примере мы даём пользователю someuser права на исполнение операторов `SELECT` и `INSERT` во всех БД их таблицах, процедурах и функциях.

Так же существует оператор для того, чтобы забирать права у пользователя.

Пример синтаксиса:

```
REVOKE INSERT ON *.* FROM 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

в этом примере мы забираем право пользователя someuser на использование оператора `INSERT` во всех БД их таблицах, процедурах и функциях.

Подробнее о синтаксисе команд можете прочитать на официальном сайте MySQL:

1. [GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)
2. [REVOKE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html)

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте про prepared statements - отсылают в mysql отдельно запрос с плейсхолдерами, затем сами переменные.
[Грамотная защита от SQL-Injection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/393450/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-sql-injection)
Также советую http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/ про pdo в частности.

Comment: Если кажется, что на вопрос уже есть ответ, надо голосовать за закрытие, а не ставить ссылку

Comment: Не вижу кнопки голосования за закрытие. Подскажите, где она.

Comment: @endless: Около вопроса ссылка «закрыть» -> выбрать «этот вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение»

Comment: @VladD вероятно, мне она недоступна из-за недостаточной репутации.

Comment: @endless: Окей, проголосовал за вас.

Comment: Можно нажать "тревога" -> "должен быть закрыт...", тогда вопрос попадет в очередь закрытия с нулем голосов.

Comment: Это не отвечает на заданный вопрос!

Answer (score 1):

> Как запретить все команды, кроме заранее перечисленных?

Думаю, для этого надо руками парсить sql-запрос.
Вряд ли подобная функциональность существует сама по себе.
Впрочем, можно похимичить с правами - это не уровень команд, но идея похожа.

> Но я спрашиваю с той целью, что бы было невозможно, провести SQL инъекцию.

А для этого просто не надо совать неэкранированные данные в запрос.
Команды тут не при чём.

Comment: экранирование спасение от конкатенации запросов (инъекций) отдельных видов.  Интересно, а как долго этот баг уже в сети? Кто-то сильно веселился с этим в своё время.

Comment: @semiromid, кажется, я не понял мысль из комментария. Или есть разные виды экранирования?

Comment: Можно не только экранировать как обычно, а еще и убирать вредные спец. символы. Или например, разрешить только определённые символы и уже  проверять их на стороне MySQL в процедуре. Вообще я имел в виду,  защита  именно от  этого вида атаки.

Comment: @semiromid: А чем экранирование обычных спецсимволов отличается от экранирования вредных спецсимволов? (И какие это — вредные?)

Comment: @semiromid нельзя

Comment: VladD Я имел в виду. экранирование обычных спецсимволов - очистка мусора. Экранировать вредные спецсимволов - эти те символы которые могут нанести непосредственно  вред кто их использует без экранирования. Или можно экранировать не только построчно, но и по символьно или некоторые символы вовсе убирать если они содержаться в сообщении.

Comment: @VladD, очень хочется дать ссылку, но не могу её найти... Про выкидывание символов.